# Xamarin - Custom Renderer - cast Form.View to Android.View

Tags: xamarin

Is it possible to get `Android.View` (and equivalent view object in `iOS`) from `Xamarin.Form.View`? I have custom control which takes dependencies to `Android.View`. I am writing custom renderer which would set that custom control as native view but I need to convert my `ContentView` (exposed as `BindableProperty`, initialized in xaml) from `Portable library` to `Android.View`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. I have written an extension that uses reflection to get the underlying native view:

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.Droid/Extensions/ViewExtensions.cs#L54-L59

Native view in the code is Android.Views.View type and View is Xamarin.Forms.View.

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.Droid/Extensions/ViewExtensions.cs#L19

The same works for iOS as well, just cast it to UIView.

Comment: Thanks - again internal property reflection, will check that. Seems like reliable Xamarin apps documentation is DotPeek..

Comment: Unfortunately that only works when View has already attached NativeView (by SetNativeControl) - I need to convert Forms.View to Android.View just after creation. (RendererFactory.GetRenderer also doesn't work as internal implementation is bugged because it only returns top-level element)

Comment: You can obtain the renderer with `Platform.GetRenderer(view)`. Although it seems that this will return the top level element only, as you mentioned, the children elements are there. Since you obtained the renderer just after Xamarin.Forms view creation (before it was actually rendered), you can trigger a layout cycle for the `ContentView`'s sub-tree. In order to do this you can extend `ViewRenderer` class (`ContentView`'s renderer) and override `OnAttachedToWindow` method, where you can trigger the layout cycle with `Element.Layout(((VisualElement)Element.Parent).Bounds)`.